# powered.exe active desktop launcher consuming high cpu

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

`powered.exe` process consuming high cpu it has description as active desktop launcher. user name is `mssqlserver`. after killing it and deleting file located also it is repeating agin after sometime.

[image]

after pressing open file location active_desktop_render_x64.dll`and`config.json` files are displaying in public music folder. after shift deleting these files are creating again. we are using seqrite endpoint security. what to do to solve this problem without server rebuild?

Comment: I am facing this problem too, i have written a script in a service to check for powered.exe and fix.exe and kill it, because it pops up again after being killed. If anyone know any solution, do let us know.

Comment: This may be a CPU mining exe.  I'm currently investigating this problem also.  I noticed Wscript and RegSvr32 running often, and it led me to finding .sct scripts calling these.